# django, passing multiple records using checkboxes

Tags: django, checkbox

I have a table of records with a html checkbox next to each record created through a for stmt. I current functionality that allows a single `Sample` to be added to a `Container`. I've added a `selectall` checkbox also via javascript

Currently each record also has an anchor: `{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id  %}` to add it to another table, this goes via a m2m and the other table has the opposite functionality.

To allow multiple records to be sent I wrap the table in a form, set the action to the above action, but how do I pass multiple records in the view?

Here's my code so far:

Template

```
  <div class="float-left col-md-4">
    <h4 class="kap">Samples</h4>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <form class="" action="{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id  %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table-striped table-dark">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="padding-left:5px;">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" />
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th>E.N.C.S</th>
              <th>Current Location</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for unassigned in unassigned_samples %}
            <tr>
              {% if unassigned not in container_contents %}
              <td style="padding-left:5px;"><input type="checkbox" /></td> # the checkbox method 
              <td style="margin:10px; padding:10px;"><a href="{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id  %}" class="badge badge-primary" role="button"> # the anchor method
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>
              </a></td>
              <td>{{ unassigned.area_easting }}.{{ unassigned.area_northing }}.{{ unassigned.context_number }}.{{ unassigned.sample_number }}</td>
                {% for container in unassigned.containers.all %}
              <td>{{ container.location_id }}.{{ container.container_name }}</td>
              {% empty %}
              <td>None</td>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>These are not the samples you are looking for!</p>
                <p>Use the above filter to search for a sample.
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default"><-- Move</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

view

```
def change_container(request, operation, pk='', fk=''):
    container = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=fk)

    if request.method == 'POST': # this is my guess work
        id_list = request.POST.getlist('') # this is my guess work

    if operation == 'add':
        ContainerSamples.add_to_container(container, sample)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        ContainerSamples.remove_from_container(container, sample)

    return redirect('depot:detailcontainer', container_id=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have guessed it right:)
Just give a name attribute to the checklist ex: `name ="checks[]"` in html
Retrieve the same in views: `some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')`
Here:

```
<thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="padding-left:5px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name ="checks[]" onclick="toggle(this);" />
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th>E.N.C.S</th>
              <th>Current Location</th>
            </tr>
 </thead>
```

```
def change_container(request, operation, pk='', fk=''):
    container = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=fk)

    if request.method == 'POST': # this is my guess work
        id_list = request.POST.getlist('checks[]') # this is my guess work
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems to work, as in no error is thrown, however, correct me if I'm wrong but passing the `checks[]` will just be an empty object? In my code it is the checkboxes in the `<td>` tags which need to pass the `{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id  %}` which will be either 1 or multiple. Any idea how to pass this, will the urls.py naturally allow this etc?

Comment: I've also tried using `<td style="padding-left:5px;"><input type="checkbox" /><input type="hidden" value="{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id  %}"</td>` I feel this is getting closer to the solution?

Comment: I didn't understand the second comment, however I guess as per ur requirements the first comment would suffice. Did u try? Drop a comment, lemme know;)

Comment: The submit button needs to send the container_id, the sample_id and the operation value to the view, at the moment the button solution allows each to be submitted 1 at a time, the checkboxes should allow multiple parameter sets to be sent to the view and batch processed. So send all of the `{% url 'depot:change_container' operation='add' pk=container.container_id fk=unassigned.sample_id %}` results to the views.py and process each as it would normally do for a single button.